AuthenticatedLayout issue with Laravel Breeze/React
Laravel Version
11.10.0
PHP Version
8.3.7
Description
When typing text between html tags inside AuthenticatedLayout  tags of breeze, it's suggesting them as VS Code emmet
Steps To Reproduce

Create a new laravel app with breeze/react.
Go to resources/js/Pages folder.
Create a new folder named 'Project' and create a new jsx file named Test.jsx inside it.
Now paste the following code

import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout";
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/react";

export default function Show({ auth, project }) {
  return (
    <AuthenticatedLayout
      user={auth.user}
      header={
        <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold leading-tight text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200">
          {`Project "${project.name}"`}
        </h2>
      }
    >
      <Head title={`Project "${project.name}"`} />
      <div className="py-12">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <div className="overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-sm dark:bg-gray-800 sm:rounded-lg">
            <div className="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
              <div>
                <img
                  src={project.image_path}
                  alt=""
                  className="object-cover w-full h-64"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-1">
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <label></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
  );
}


Now type anything between label tags. It will start suggesting your typed words as if they are html tags.
All words-typing adjacent to html tags are suggesting as html emmets

Here's my editorconfig file for further info

I disabled all vs code extensions and stopped all servers, but nothing changes.
I am new to React. Please help me. It's very frustrating 
